# Is it possible for an equilibrium to be Trembling Hand Perfect for one player but not another in an asymmetric game?

Tags: game-theory

Is it possible for an equilibrium to be Trembling Hand Perfect for one player but not another (in an asymmetric game)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible for a strategy profile of one player to be trembling hand perfect and not the other.

Generally speaking, trembling hand perfect is used in the equilibrium sense. Certainly for an equilibrium to be called trembling hand perfect, the strategy profiles of all players must also be so.

Comment: This answer would be very nice if it would begin with the word "No" instead of "Yes". As laid out in the second paragraph of the answer.